# How can I remove the whitespace at the end of each line

Tags: c++

```
void printSudoku9x9(int grid[9][9]) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            cout << grid[y][x] <<' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Split the loop on 8 iterations and final cout without the space.

Comment: `for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++){
 if(x==8){
  cout << grid[y][x] << endl;
 }else{
  cout << grid[y][x] <<' ';
 }
}`

Comment: How do I remove it? ... Don't put it there to begin with ...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing a space *after* each character and dealing with the end, print a space *before* each character printed except for when `(x==0)`.

```
void printSudoku9x9(int grid[9][9]) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            char leading = (x == 0) ? "" : " ";
            cout << leading << grid[y][x];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to use the  `'\b'` [escape-character](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) which moves the output cursor back to one character:

```
void printSudoku9x9(int grid[9][9]) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            cout << grid[y][x] <<' ';
        cout << '\b' << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer with an explanation of _why_ this works.

Comment: Well, I was sure that having obvious right answer anybody will be able to find that is it and how it works. Anyway, agree, updated. Thanks.